# Adding Video in android through Video View

Tags: android, video, addition, android-videoview

I'v trying to add a video in my Android App. But it just shows me a blank screen and then App crashes.

Here is the code
Any help will be apritiated.

Thanks

```
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);



    DisplayMetrics dm;
    VideoView video_player_view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_player_view);

    android.widget.MediaController media_Controller = new android.widget.MediaController(getApplicationContext(),null );
    video_player_view.setMediaController(media_Controller);
    dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    video_player_view.setMinimumWidth(width);
    video_player_view.setMinimumHeight(height);
    video_player_view.setVideoPath("/sdcard/video");
    video_player_view.start();
```

Here is the xml for this.

```
 <FrameLayout 
     android:id="@+id/video_frame" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 


     <VideoView android:id="@+id/video_player_view"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


     </FrameLayout>
```

Here is my Logcat. Also please tell me what is to be added as path in setVideoPath.

```
01-07 13:48:58.304: E/Trace(25305): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-07 13:49:39.474: E/MediaPlayer(25305): MediaPlayer: Uri ........ 
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at                android.widget.MediaController.updateFloatingWindowLayout(MediaController.java:171)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.widget.MediaController.access$000(MediaController.java:71)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at       android.widget.MediaController$1.onLayoutChange(MediaController.java:181)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13763)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1922)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1033)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4295)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4827)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
01-07 13:49:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(25305):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 13:49:40.185: E/MediaPlayer(25305): error (100, 0)
01-07 13:49:40.185: E/MediaPlayer(25305): Mediaserver died in 4 state
```

Comment: "/sdcard/video" is not valid path for video and also add loq with question to get more help

Comment: Thanks, but what is to be added at he path section then ? The path of drawable ?

Comment: add  full path of video where it is stored on sdcard

Comment: Thanks. Much appritiated.Now its getting the video. But crashes just after first frame of video.

Comment: app crashing due to `media_Controller`

Comment: Can you please help me through code. What should i change with media_controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
MediaController media_Controller = new MediaController(getApplicationContext());
        video_player_view.setMediaController(media_Controller);
        dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int height = dm.heightPixels;
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        video_player_view.setMinimumWidth(width);
        video_player_view.setMinimumHeight(height);
        video_player_view.setVideoPath("/sdcard/video");
        video_player_view.start();
```

Comment: this way its give me an error on media_controller initialization "Add Argument to match MediaController(Context, Token)"

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, just do Ctrl+Shift+O

Comment: Thanks you were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Set `MediaController` for `ViewView` as:

```
MediaController media_Controller = new MediaController(CurrentActivity.this);
video_player_view.setMediaController(media_Controller);
```

Comment: this way its give me an error on media_controller initialization "Add Argument to match MediaController(Context, Token)"

Comment: @SajawalSohail: you can see here class have three constructor :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html

Comment: Yes. That is exactly the thing confusing me. Why is eclipse giving me and error here than ? This should be supposed to work with just Context

Comment: @SajawalSohail: all constructor version is available from API level 1 so error is not possible

Comment: Thanks for your help. But that's not my case here. I think there is a problem in my SDK that its showing me an error here.